# unsigned to hex digit

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, hex

I got a problem that says: Form a character array based on an unsigned int. Array will represent that int in hexadecimal notation. Do this using bitwise operators.

So, my ideas is the following: I create a mask that has 1's for its 4 lowest value bits.
I push the bits of the given int by 4 to the right and use & on that int and mask. I repeat until (int != 0). My question is: when I get individual hex digits (packs of 4 bits), how do I convert them to a char? For example, I get:

```
x & mask = 1101(2) = 13(10) = D(16)
```

Is there a function to convert an int to hex representation, or do I have to use brute force with switch statement or whatever else?

I almost forgot, I am doing this in C :)

Here is what I mean:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BLOCK 4

    int main() {
        unsigned int x, y, i, mask;
        char a[4];

        printf("Enter a positive number: ");
        scanf("%u", &x);
        for (i = sizeof(usnsigned int), mask = ~(~0 << 4); x; i--, x >>= BLOCK) {
            y = x & mask;
            a[i] = FICTIVE_NUM_TO_HEX_DIGIT(y);
        }

        print_array(a);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/)

Comment: `char hex_digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF"; string_rep[i] = hex_digits[x & mask];`

Comment: @DanielFischer: Can you make that comment an answer?

Comment: `#define FICTIVE_NUM_TO_HEX_DIGIT(n) "0123456789ABCDEF"[n]`

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. The simplest method to convert an integer in the range from 0 to 15 to a hexadecimal digit is to use a lookup table,

```
char hex_digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

and index into that,

```
a[i] = hex_digits[y];
```

in your code.

Remarks:

```
char a[4];
```

is probably too small. One hexadecimal digit corresponds to four bits, so with `CHAR_BIT == 8`, you need up to `2*sizeof(unsigned)` `char`s to represent the number, generally, `(CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned int) + 3) / 4`. Depending on what `print_array` does, you may need to 0-terminate `a`.

```
for (i = sizeof(usnsigned int), mask = ~(~0 << 4); x; i--, x >>= BLOCK)
```

initialising `i` to `sizeof(unsigned int)` skips the most significant bits, `i` should be initialised to the last valid index into `a` (except for possibly the 0-terminator, then the penultimate valid index).

The mask can more simply be defined as `mask = 0xF`, that has the added benefit of not invoking undefined behaviour, which

```
mask = ~(~0 << 4)
```

probably does. `0` is an `int`, and thus `~0` is one too. On two's complement machines (that is almost everything nowadays), the value is `-1`, and shifting negative integers left is undefined behaviour.

Comment: 1) yes, a[4] is too small, I have changed it to sizeof(unsigned int) * 2

Comment: 2) mask = ~(~0 << 4) did the job right, but I like mask = 0xF a lot more

Answer (score 0):

```
char buffer[10] = {0};
int h = 17;
sprintf(buffer, "%02X", h);
```

Comment: The `X` format specifier corresponds to an *unsigned int* argument. This is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Question also says "Do this using bitwise operators" (e.g. most likely a homework question intended to get students familiar with bitwise operators).

Comment: @modifiablelvalue There's an exemption: if the varargs type is an integer type, signed or unsigned, and the argument type is the corresponding type with the other signedness, and the value is representable in both types, the behaviour is not undefined.

Comment: @DanielFischer: According to which section of the standard?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue 7.16.1.1 paragraph 2. ... the behaviour is undefined except in the following two cases "- one type is a signed integer type, the other type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;" (the other is `void*` and pointer to a character type).

Comment: @DanielFischer I think we should take this to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28118/room-for-modifiable-lvalue-and-daniel-fischer).

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the impact of potential padding bits when shifting, as shifting by anything equal to or greater than the number of value bits that exist in an integer type is undefined behaviour.

Perhaps you could terminate the string first using: `array[--size] = '\0';`, write the smallest nibble (hex digit) using `array[--size] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[value & 0x0f]`, move onto the next nibble using: `value >>= 4`, and repeat while `value > 0`. When you're done, return `array + size` or `&array[size]` so that the caller knows where the hex sequence begins.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
char hex_digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

for (i = 0; i < ((sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT + 3) / 4); i++) {
    digit = (x >> (sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT - 4)) & 0x0F;
    x = x << 4;
    a[i] = hex_digits[digit];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is where I got:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BLOCK 4

void printArray(char*, int);

int main() {
    unsigned int x, mask;
    int size = sizeof(unsigned int) * 2, i;
    char a[size], hexDigits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        a[i] = 0;

    printf("Enter a positive number: ");
    scanf("%u", &x);
    for (i = size - 1, mask = ~(~0 << 4); x; i--, x >>= BLOCK) {
        a[i] = hexDigits[x & mask];
    }

    printArray(a, size);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void printArray(char a[], int n) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%c", a[i]);

    putchar('\n');
}
```

I have compiled, it runs and it does the job correctly. I don't know... Should I be worried that this problem was a bit hard for me? At faculty, during exams, we must write our code by hand, on a piece of paper... I don't imagine I would have done this right.
Is there a better (less complicated) way to do this problem? Thank you all for help :)

Comment: `a[i] = hexDigits[x & mask];` looks wrong, to me. Have you tested this for larger values, like 1048576?

Comment: Ah. My bad. I thought you were shifting mask, rather than x. You might want to consider using `~(UINT_MAX << 4)` instead of `~(~0 << 4)`, though.